# elasticsearch unable to start - Java exception No such method: java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)

Tags: java, exception, elasticsearch

Been trying to upgrade elasticsearch from 2.x to 5.x and while doing this, since straight through upgradation is impossible, a fresh install was necessary. Hence, I downloaded the deb file and tried to install the newer version. I was successful in installing elasticsearch. When I tried to start the server the following exception did raise:

```
 * Starting Elasticsearch Server
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.elasticsearch.env.ESFileStore.<init>(ESFileStore.java:65)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.createEnv(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:72)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84)
  [fail]

Java version of my machine is:
java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b108)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b50, mixed mode)
```

I have an openjdk-7-jre running in the machine as well.
Can't find a workaround to this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you really sure that you server starts with java version which the new version of elasticserch needs? For a try you can disable java 7.

Comment: I didn't think of that @reporter. Yet, I've fixed it by installing openjdk-8-jre.

Answer (score 0):

After three hours of dwelling over resources, I've fixed the issue. There seems to be a version compatibility mismatch across ES 5.x and openjdk-7-jre. I uninstalled the existing openjdk-7-jre and **installed openjdk-8-jre**, restarted the server again. Elasticsearch is up and running :)